# SQL create column with select in select and subtract this with another column, to create a new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, installation, isnull

I'm new at SQL and I have a question about my code as shown underneath:

```
SELECT membernummer, name, c.ammount, c.terms,      
      (select SUM(isnull(amount, 0)) 
       from payments p where m.member_ID = p.member_ID and p.year = c.year) AS payed
From member m 
  INNER JOIN contribution c ON m.member_ID = c.member_ID
where c.year = 2014
```

Now I would like to substract 'payed'(actual payments)  from 'amount'(which is contribution that needs to be payed).

I tried referring to ' payed' in other sections and subtracting it, but if I am correct you can't refer to an alias in SQL. 
I also tried adding another select in select:

```
(select SUM(isnull(amount, 0)) 
 from payments p 
 where m.member_ID = p.member_ID 
   and p.year = c.year) - sum(amount) AS 'still to be payed'
```

This just gives me an error.

I also have a small question about the ISNULL function in my code, it is supposed to change ' null' in the 'payed' column to 0. But implemented like this it isn't working.

Thanks for looking at my code. If you need more information please ask, I'm rather new at this so I might miss obvious things.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Using single quotes for identifiers (`AS 'still to be payed'`) is invalid (standard) SQL.

Comment: Microsoft SQL server management studio. Thank you for the edit. I adjusted the single quotes in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood well I think this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT,membernummer, name, c.ammount, c.terms, payed_sum, amount_sum, amount_sum - payed_sum balance
from (
    SELECT membernummer, name, c.ammount, c.terms,
    (select SUM(coalese(amount, 0)) from payments p where m.member_ID = p.member_ID and p.year = c.year) AS amount_sum,
    (select SUM(colasce(payed, 0)) from payments p where m.member_ID = p.member_ID and p.year = c.year) AS payed_sum
    From member m INNER JOIN contribution c ON m.member_ID = c.member_ID where c.year = 2014
) calc
```

about isnull, please inform which database you're using. Each database has different function for this. I substituted it for the coalesce function, but it may not be available in your db.

Comment: Thanks for you quick feedback! I applied your way of using select in select and for the most part it is working. I still have some small problems, but I'll figure that out myself. Thank you very much

Comment: Coalese isn't working in my DB (can't figure out what kind it is...), I' ll try some more things with isnull. Thanks again.

Comment: np. please run the following SQL and tell us the result in order to help you with isnull and coalesce: Select @@version